# What's the difference between User.Read vs OpenID/Profile/Email Permissions in AzureAD App Registration for an app that will sign in users?

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-teams

When creating multi-tenant apps that will use Azure AD Authentication to sign users in, various samples on GitHub seem to suggest that the App Registration should include the following permissions clubbed under OpenId.

```
email   View users' email address
offline_access   Maintain access to data you have given it access to
openid     Sign users in
profile   View users' basic profile
```

(See for example: https://github.com/OfficeDev/microsoft-teams-sample-auth-node Section 12)

While following the samples on the Azure portal itself, the quickstarts create an App registration with just this one permission

User.Read  Sign in and read user profile

Is Microsoft's Azure AD User.Read permission a superset of the generic openid's  email, openid and profile permissions?

When creating a consent URL in the [https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/adminconsent?client_id={client-id}](https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/adminconsent?client_id=%7Bclient-id%7D) form, only the User.Read seems to appear.

What is the recommended set of permissions that are recommended for a basic app that needs to sign users in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Hence the question if user.read subsumes open_id, email and profile
> perms?

No, `user.read` does not contain them, they are independent permissions.

> I have set these required perms but in the consent popup shown to the
> Azure AD admin, email and profile and openid permissions do not show
> up; only offlne_access and user.read shows.

`email` `offline_access` `openid` `profile` is usually the permissions of the OIDC protocol. There are some differences between **oauth2.0** and [openid connect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-protocols-oidc). If you only need to log in as a user, you only need to use **openid connect**, and it will only return you the **id token** of the logged in user. Regarding why the email openid profile is not displayed on the admin consent page, I think this is a problem that is still being fixed, but I don’t think you need to worry about these because these permissions themselves are permissions that do not require the administrator’s consent. When you add them in **API permissions**, you can use them directly.

Comment: If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.) Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

I just spent quite a while testing this as part of my own learning today, and here's what I found.

### tl;dr

The `openid` scope will get you an `id_token`, and an `access_token` that allows you to call the UserInfo endpoint (https://graph.microsoft.com/oidc/userinfo). If you want to call any of the Graph APIs, (other than UserInfo) then you'll want (at least) the `User.Read` scope.

### The Details

I have a test AzureAD tenant in which I created a brand-new client app registration (with a SPA endpoint) and a brand-new user, thus ensuring there was no residual 'consent' anywhere.

I then used the browser to sign-in with a hand-crafted URL to request **only** the `openid` scope. With line breaks added and some chars redacted this was:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/a8257b21-...6263/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
  client_id=b3f87624-...e5b&
  response_type=code&
  redirect_uri=https://localhost&
  response_mode=query&
  scope=openid&
  state=12345&
  code_challenge=LrTIpxRwK...
  code_challenge_method=S256&
  prompt=login
```

For this I got the below consent prompt:

[image]

It's interesting to note that it asked to "*View your basic profile*" and "*Maintain access to data...*" when I didn't ask for `profile` or `offline_access` scopes.

I extracted the authorization code from the response and sent it to the `https://login.microsoftonline.com/{{tenant_id}}/oauth2/v2.0/token` endpoint with the necessary fields.

The `id_token` I got back didn't include claims the `profile` scope would imply, showing only the below

```
{
  "aud": "b3f87624-...2fb5367e5b",
  "iss": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/a8257b21...263/v2.0",
  "iat": 1642367777,
  "nbf": 1642367777,
  "exp": 1642371677,
  "rh": "0.AUYAIXs...L7U2fluAAB0.",
  "sub": "tcK...WXUvzWqAc",
  "tid": "a82...6263",
  "uti": "SjLRuw...jlhAA",
  "ver": "2.0"
}
```

However interestingly the `access_token` it returned is for the `Graph` audience (`00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000`) did list the scopes as including `profile` and `email`, and did include claims related to those, e.g. (with some omitted for clarity)

```
{
  "aud": "00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000",
  "iss": "https://sts.windows.net/a82...6263/",
  "app_displayname": "TestApp",
  "appid": "b3f87...67e5b",
  "family_name": "Bull",
  "given_name": "Pit",
  "idtyp": "user",
  "ipaddr": "67.183.2.129",
  "name": "Pit Bull",
  "oid": "08a5...673de",
  "scp": "openid profile email",
  "sub": "6JrD7...phCH7Y",
  "tid": "a825...36263",
  "unique_name": "pit@example.dev",
  "upn": "pit@example.dev",
  "ver": "1.0"
}
```

(Note: Obviously you shouldn't look in tokens that aren't for your audience, but it's all there in clear text, so?)

I did also get a refresh token back, which I saved for later.

With that access token I could call the UserInfo endpoint and also see the `*name` claims, which would indicate `profile` scope (I forget to set the `email` on my test user, else I'm guessing that would have shown too).

From https://graph.microsoft.com/oidc/userinfo

```
{
    "sub": "tcK6D...UvzWqAc",
    "name": "Pit Bull",
    "family_name": "Bull",
    "given_name": "Pit",
    "picture": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/photo/$value"
}
```

However, with that same access token, if I tried to call any Graph APIs such as https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me or https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/organization I was met with the following response.

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "Authorization_RequestDenied",
        "message": "Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "2022-01-16T21:52:18",
            "request-id": "e4f58...1611",
            "client-request-id": "e4f5...a1611"
        }
    }
}
```

By running through the same flow again but this time with the scopes `openid profile email`, the only difference I could ascertain was that the `id_token` now included the below claims (and again, probably would have had the email address if I'd configured it on the account)

```
  "name": "Pit Bull",
  "oid": "08a5...73de",
  "preferred_username": "pit@example.dev",
```

The access token looked the same, and the UserInfo result was the same (which makes sense if the access_token to auth to it looked the same). I'd also note I didn't get prompted for any additional consent, which would imply `profile` and `email` were implicitly added to my initial `openid`-only scope request.

At this point I took a break to feed the kids, and when I came back a couple hours later decided to try out the refresh token I received (without requesting `offline_access` scope). It worked fine and I got refreshed tokens, so this seems to be implicitly added also when just requesting `openid`.

For my next test I sent the same hand-crafted request to authenticate but included the `User.Read` scope. As expected, I got prompted for the additional consent:

[image]

It's interesting to note how it mentions "*..and read basic company information*". This aligns with the docs at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/permissions-reference which state of `User.Read`: "*With the User.Read permission, an app can also read the basic company information of the signed-in user for a work or school account through the organization resource.*".

All the tokens I got back from this looked similar to before, but obviously with the addition of the `User.Read` scp in the access token. Now making requests to certain Graph APIs was met with success. For example:

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me or https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/pit@example.dev

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users/$entity",
    "businessPhones": [],
    "displayName": "Pit Bull",
    "givenName": "Pit",
    "jobTitle": null,
    "mail": null,
    "mobilePhone": null,
    "officeLocation": null,
    "preferredLanguage": null,
    "surname": "Bull",
    "userPrincipalName": "pit@example.dev",
    "id": "08a53...b673de"
}
```

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/directReports (I didn't have any direct reports configured, but it was a successful query rather than access denied)

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#directoryObjects",
    "value": []
}
```

And https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/organization (trimmed for readability - and again, I'd not set up org details for this account, hence the `null`s)

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#organization",
    "value": [
        {
            "id": "a8257...736263",
            "businessPhones": [],
            "city": null,
            "country": null,
            "postalCode": null,
            "preferredLanguage": null,
            "state": null,
            "tenantType": "AAD",
            "directorySizeQuota": {
                "used": 39,
                "total": 300000
            },
            "verifiedDomains": [
                {
                    "capabilities": "Email, OfficeCommunicationsOnline",
                    "isDefault": false,
                    "isInitial": true,
                    "name": "example.onmicrosoft.com",
                    "type": "Managed"
                },
                {
                    "capabilities": "None",
                    "isDefault": true,
                    "isInitial": false,
                    "name": "example.dev",
                    "type": "Managed"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

So there you have it. Add `User.Read` if you want to query anything from the Graph APIs, else just use `openid` (and optionally `profile email`) if you are happy just signing users in and using the `id_token` for your needs.

As a footnote to this I'd also recommend reading the couple paragraphs at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/permissions-reference#remarks-15 . I was only testing with a v2 endpoint, but it does look like `User.Read` used to be required just to sign-in with the v1 endpoint, so it being included by default may be a residual effect of that. As it states of the V1 endpoint: "*To successfully return an ID token, you must also make sure that the User.Read permission is configured when you register your app.*"

Comment: Thanks much for your rigorous testing and for documenting this.

Comment: What I take from this is, `User.Read` is basically equivalent to `openid` + `email` + `profile` + gives you access to Graph API. And also, `offline_access` doesn't actually do anything because the `refresh_token` will be included with either `openid` or `User.Read`

Answer (score 0):

At this time, the offline_access ("Maintain access to data you have given it access to") and user.read ("Sign you in and read your profile") permissions are automatically included in the initial consent to an application. These permissions are generally required for proper app functionality - offline_access gives the app access to refresh tokens, critical for native and web apps, while user.read gives access to the sub claim, allowing the client or app to correctly identify the user over time and access rudimentary user information. please refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-permissions-and-consent#requesting-individual-user-consent)

Comment: Thanks. I guess the question is when asking a foreign tenant Admin to consent, do we need to specifically ask for openid, email, profile or does user.read provide the same information. In my muti-tenant app, I have set these required perms but in the consent popup shown to the Azure AD admin, email and profile and openid permissions do not show up; only offlne_access and user.read shows. Hence the question if user.read subsumes open_id, email and profile perms?